# Witt Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

For Witt Lie Algebras over field of characterestic $p>3$ we know that $\operatorname{dim}W(n;m):=np^{|m|}$ , such that $|m|=m_1+⋯+m_n$   . I would like to know what is the dimension of Witt algebras over $\mathrm {GF}(2)$. Why $\operatorname{dim}W(2,1)= ?$

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to define W(n; m) for the unenlightened. Is it the $W\left(n, \overline{m}\right)$ in Definition 1.3 of Theresia Nolte's http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gerhard.Hiss/Students/DiplomarbeitNolte.pdf ?

Comment: What is the source of definitions and notation on which the question is based?   There are somewhat different approaches in the literature to the Jacobson-Witt algebras, but for instance where does the claim $\dim W(2) = 3$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ come from?

Comment: The main source is a paper titled: "
Some new simple Lie algebras in characteristic 2" published by Professor B.Eick.

Comment: After the recent edit this question is even more unclear...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is only a problem of notation here. The Jacobson-Witt algebra $W(m; \underline{n})$ is known to be simple of dimension $mp^{\vert n\vert}$ (where $\vert n \vert=n_1+n_2 \cdots + n_m$)  except when $m = 1$ and the ground field has characteristic $p=2$. In the latter case the derived subalgebra $W(1; \underline{n})^{(1)}$ is simple of dimension $2^{\vert n \vert} − 1$,  provided $\vert n \vert >1$. So I think that $W(1; \underline{2})^{(1)}$ is the Lie algebra the user is really referring to. Up to isomorphisms, this is the only $3$-dimensional simple Lie algebra over $GF(2)$. It has a basis $\{a,b,c \}$ such that $[a,b]=c$, $[b,c]=a$, $[c,a]=b$.

Comment: this is the exact answer I was kooking for, in addition to that I would like to know how the dimension of W(1;1) and W(2;1) be computed over GF(2)? thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: A standard reference is "H. Strade - R. Farnsteiner: Modular Lie Algebras and Their Representation, Dekker, New York, 1988." You are referred to Chapter 4 of this book.

Comment: I have already studied this book, but I am a little confused about somethings, for instance according theorem from mentioned book (page 149) if m=1 and p=2 then W(m;n) is not simple, whereas W(2;1) over GF(2) is 16-dimensional simple Lie algebra!this matter has been stated in paper titled "Some new simple Lie algebras in characteristic 2" by B. Eick.

Comment: W(2;(1,1)) has indeed dimension 8 over GF(2) and it is isomorphic to sl(3, GF(2)), so it is not clear to me what you are really asking... Maybe, you could find the paper "Simple Lie algebras of low dimension over GF(2)" by Vaughan-Lee useful for your purpose. As a final suggestion, if the problem is due to notation you may need to contact the paper's author directly.

Answer (score 1):

Since it not exactly clear, which Lie algebra is meant, let me note that the Lie algebra $W(1;\underline{2})$ is $4$-dimensional over $\Bbb F_2$, see the article by Helmut Strade [Lie algebras of small dimension](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601413). Its commutator subalgebra $W(1;\underline{2})^{(1)}$ is the unique simple Lie algebra of dimension $3$ over $\Bbb F_2$ mentioned above.